# Foreign Key confusion

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am new to database and making a gym management system, I implemented a database from the tutorials on www.homeandlearn.co.uk. I have completed the project without foreign keys. Now I have to link tables but I am getting this error:

> Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.
>   Please correct the following errors and try again.
>
> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[member_info]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.

I do not know what is this error  about. Please tell me how to fix this? Do i have to create a new database now or I can still use the foreign keys in the same database? I am using Visual Studio 2012. All help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Cheers,

I do have a primary key, and I have set it to increment by 1. see this is my table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[member_info] (
[Id]                INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[memberName]        NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[father_name]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[age]               NCHAR (10)    NULL,
[address]           NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[contact]           NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[height]            NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[weight]            NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[chest]             NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[triceps_biceps]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[waist]             NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[shoulders]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[thighs]            NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[calves]            NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[instructor]        NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[date_of_admission] DATE          NULL,
[photo]             IMAGE         NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
CONSTRAINT [FK_member_info_instructor_info] FOREIGN KEY ([instructor]) REFERENCES
[instructor_info]([instructor])
);
```

This is my member_info and below is my instructor_info table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[instructor_info] (
[InstructorID]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[instructor]        NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[father_name]       NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[age]               NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[address]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[contact]           NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[height]            NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[weight]            NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[chest]             NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[triceps_biceps]    NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[waist]             NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[shoulders]         NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[thighs]            NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[calves]            NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[memberName]           NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[date_of_admission] DATE           NULL,
[photo]             IMAGE          NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([InstructorID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Does the table contains data? If yes, then the foreign keys in other tables must have the exact datatype and the exact values as the parent table column. Otherwise you would not be able to create the constraint.

Comment: Are you sure this is MySQL - looks like an MSSql error to me

Comment: Show us the table structures, and how you're establishing the FK link from one table to the other!

Comment: @DamienJoe I have posted the tables, please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: @Liath I am not sure its MySQL because I am new to database, I created it from the Add New Item from the Project menu in VS2012. It is a service-based-database.

Comment: @marc_s Can you tell me now what is wrong?

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi marc has summed it up in detail in his post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is your table `instructor_info`

```
[dbo].[instructor_info] 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([InstructorID] ASC)
```

So if you want to reference that primary key from your table `member_info`, you must reference **that exact column name** (`InstructorID`).

So your current FK constraint won't work - you need to reference that column name, and you must use the same datatype.

Change your table `member_info` to use

```
[Instructor_ID] INT
```

(instead of the `[instructor] NVARCHAR(50)` column) and then change your FK constraint to:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_member_info_instructor_info] 
FOREIGN KEY ([instructor_ID]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[instructor_info]([Instructor_ID])
```

Any **foreign key** in a table must reference the other table's **primary key** (or a unique constraint) - it cannot just reference any column you like....

Answer (score 2):

You have to create primary keys for your tables in order to reference them in your foreign keys. Below an example of creating a table with a primary key, so you don't stumble on this error later on.

```
CREATE TABLE member_info (
 id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Link for MYSQL documentation on this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

EDIT: since my answer was posted, the tag changed from mysql to mssql, as well as a snippet to provide more info. For history purposes, I'm adding the code below to answer the new question.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[instructor_info] (
[InstructorID]      INT            PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[instructor]        NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[father_name]       NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[age]               NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[address]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[contact]           NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[height]            NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[weight]            NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[chest]             NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[triceps_biceps]    NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[waist]             NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[shoulders]         NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[thighs]            NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[calves]            NCHAR (10)     NULL,
[memberName]        NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[date_of_admission] DATE           NULL,
[photo]             IMAGE          NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[member_info] (
[Id]                INT           PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[memberName]        NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[father_name]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[age]               NCHAR (10)    NULL,
[address]           NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[contact]           NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[height]            NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[weight]            NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[chest]             NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[triceps_biceps]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[waist]             NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[shoulders]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[thighs]            NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[calves]            NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[instructor]        INT           FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES instructor_info(InstructorID),
[date_of_admission] DATE          NULL,
[photo]             IMAGE         NULL
);
```

Comment: I think I can only make a primary key a foreign key. I tried this and this is working.

Answer (score 0):

For you to have a foreign key referencing a table you must have a primary key on that table. Check your member_info table and make sure there is one.

Comment: True, although if there isn't a PK on there at all I'd start there!

Comment: I have a primary key on my all tables. :(